# <Apex:pageMessages/> not showing errors

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation-rule

I'm having problem showing errors in my page, I have validation rule on the custom_object__c which I have created and its `Active` but when I try to save the page instead of getting the validation rule error on my `apex:pageMessages` I'm getting Visualforce Error

here is the erorr showing:

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   XXXXX; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION ]
>
> Error is in expression '{!Save}' in component  in
>   page employeePage: Class.EmployeeCtrl.Save:

What do I need to do to show error on `apex:pageMessages`?

Comment: try to use try catch block and check the exception message. ? I guess you will get the above update filed error but also you will get the message.. totally you will get 2 error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try like this :

```
try {  
    insert Account;
} 
catch (DMLException e) {
    ApexPages.addMessages(e);
}
```